# How to safely delete old version of sdk from xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have used xcode for a long time and I just found out that it takes a large amount of spaces. After observing the folder spaces I found below folders contain old version of downloaded SDKs.

```
$ ls ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/
Archives            DeveloperPortal 6.1.1.db    DeveloperPortal 7.2.db-wal
DerivedData         DeveloperPortal 6.1.1.db-shm    DeveloperPortal 8.0.db
DeveloperPortal 5.0.1.db    DeveloperPortal 6.1.1.db-wal    DeveloperPortal 8.0.db-shm
DeveloperPortal 5.0.1.db-shm    DeveloperPortal 6.1.db      DeveloperPortal 8.0.db-wal
DeveloperPortal 5.0.1.db-wal    DeveloperPortal 6.1.db-shm  DeveloperPortal 8.3.2.db
DeveloperPortal 5.0.2.db    DeveloperPortal 6.1.db-wal  DeveloperPortal 8.3.2.db-shm
DeveloperPortal 5.0.2.db-shm    DeveloperPortal 6.2.db      DeveloperPortal 8.3.2.db-wal
DeveloperPortal 5.0.2.db-wal    DeveloperPortal 6.2.db-shm  DocumentationCache
DeveloperPortal 5.0.db      DeveloperPortal 6.2.db-wal  GPUToolsAgent.sock
DeveloperPortal 5.0.db-shm  DeveloperPortal 6.4.db      Installs
DeveloperPortal 5.0.db-wal  DeveloperPortal 6.4.db-shm  Products
DeveloperPortal 5.1.1.db    DeveloperPortal 6.4.db-wal  Snapshots
DeveloperPortal 5.1.1.db-shm    DeveloperPortal 7.0.1.db    UserData
DeveloperPortal 5.1.1.db-wal    DeveloperPortal 7.0.1.db-shm    iOS Device Logs
DeveloperPortal 6.0.1.db    DeveloperPortal 7.0.1.db-wal    iOS Device Logs.db
DeveloperPortal 6.0.1.db-shm    DeveloperPortal 7.2.db      iOS DeviceSupport
DeveloperPortal 6.0.1.db-wal    DeveloperPortal 7.2.db-shm
```

it includes a lot unused versions of SDK. Is there a way for me to remove them in Xocde? Can I just delete these folders from finder?

Comment: Those are not SDKs.